# Getting android.compileSdkVersion is missing! error gradle build

Tags: android, git, maven, gradle, android-library

I am trying to build my library and upload it to the repository, but unfortunatly gradle build fails. I have spent several hours trying to fix this error, but nothing what I tried didn't help.
Here is my `build.gradle` from root project dir.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And build.gradle from my module directory

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.bintray"
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
version = "1.0.0"
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/CROSP/AndroidHorizontalRecyclerView'      // Homepage URL of the library
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/CROSP/AndroidHorizontalRecyclerView.git'   // Git repository URL
group = "com.github.crosp.horizontalrecyclerview"                      // Maven Group ID for the artifact

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'

}
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'

                // Add your description here
                name 'Android Horizontal Recycler View with Headerr'
                description = 'Android Horizontal Recycler View with Header project for displaying horizontal list on Android '
                url siteUrl

                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'crosp'
                        name 'Alexandr Crospenko'
                        email 'crosp@ukr.net'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

// https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin
bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        // it is the name that appears in bintray when logged
        name = "crosp"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
        version {
            gpg {
                sign = true //Determines whether to GPG sign the files. The default is false
                passphrase = properties.getProperty("bintray.gpg.password") //Optional. The passphrase for GPG signing'
            }
//            mavenCentralSync {
//                sync = true //Optional (true by default). Determines whether to sync the version to Maven Central.
//                user = properties.getProperty("bintray.oss.user") //OSS user token
//                password = properties.getProperty("bintray.oss.password") //OSS user password
//                close = '1' //Optional property. By default the staging repository is closed and artifacts are released to Maven Central. You can optionally turn this behaviour off (by puting 0 as value) and release the version manually.
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have added some configurations into my `local.properties` file

```
sdk.dir=/home/crosp/Android/Sdk
bintray.user=####
bintray.apikey=####

bintray.gpg.password=####
bintray.oss.user=####
bintray.oss.password=####
```

The problem is that I get following error after `gradle bintrayUpload`.

```
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.compileSdkVersion is missing!
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:80)
```

And at the end of error message output I get following

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/crosp/AndroidStudioProjects/HorizontalList/horizontalrecyclerview/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':horizontalrecyclerview'.
> org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

This error related with the "compile sdk version" is because you are using Gradle 2.4

Check in your Android Studio preferences and search for Gradle. If you have the "Use local gradle distribution" checked see the version and try to change to the "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)"

Now if that not works. Check in your project structure, in the option "Project" probably it's using the "Gradle version 2.4" so set to 2.2.1

In the worst case maybe you are using your console, so run: gradle --version and check your gradle version.

Try to avoid to use the "Gradle 2.4" because it has problems related with some tasks in the Android Studio.